# Can't log in Heroku

Tags: heroku, salesforce, multi-factor-authentication, authenticator

When i am trying to log in Heroku, after entering email and password, heroku asks me to verify my identity :

"To keep your account secure, we verify your identity.
Enter the code generated by your authenticator app."

But i didnt setup any authenticator app for this and cant receive any codes for it. Heroku Support sends me back to login, but i cant login. And i tried to login via heroku cli, it sends me back to browser :

https://verify.salesforce.com/v1/verify/

[login](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yoc0o.png)

[authentication page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pXMQG.png)

Comment: Also i deployed my frontend via Heroku, so i somehow created Heroku account earlier and set up 2 factor authentication

Comment: I just want to cancel my subscription in Heroku (it costs 20 dollars per month and i have a lot of subscriptions)

Answer (score 0):

If for some reason you lose access to your two-factor device and your recovery codes, you have three additional ways you can regain access.

If you’re logged into Dashboard in a browser, you can turn off two-factor authentication for your account on the Settings page. You’re asked for your password.
If you have a valid CLI session on your computer, you can use the CLI to turn off two-factor authentication with the command heroku 2fa:disable. You’re asked for your password.
If you set an SMS number, you can obtain a two-factor code via SMS. Choose Get a code via SMS when logging in.
If none of these methods work for you, you’re not guaranteed to regain access to your account. For help, email account-lockout@heroku.com. We can only disable two-factor authentication if we can verify your ownership of the account, which isn’t always possible.

source: [https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/two-factor-authentication#:~:text=If%20you%20have%20a%20valid,via%20SMS%20when%20logging%20in](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/two-factor-authentication#:%7E:text=If%20you%20have%20a%20valid,via%20SMS%20when%20logging%20in).

Comment: Thanks, problem is none of this helped. I emailed to heroku but have no response. Also i have monthly subscription which i need to cancel, but i dont know how to do it without log in to account that have this subscription